# Number Keys not Changing View

Tags: interface, 3d-view

As I understand it, the number keys are used for changing the view, but they are changing the *3D Layers* instead. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: @ShadyPuck [3D layers](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/layers.html) are not [Render layers](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/post_process/layers.html)

Comment: @MrZak Huh. I always thought they were sort of interchangeable. They are related, tho. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @ShadyPuck if you aren't sure about definitions consider googling / checking manual about them first.

Comment: @MrZak Noted, but sorry if I wasn't clear, because I _was_ sure that I was correct.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the *numpad* keys, not the number keys. However, if you are on a laptop or similar device that does not have a numpad, you can do the following.

Go to *File > User Preferences > Input tab* and check *Emulate Numpad*. This will allow the number keys at the top of your keyboard to function as numpad keys. You will, however, lose the functionality to switch layers, the shortcut to add a *Subdivision surface* object modifier, and whatever else they are good for. Make sure to click *Save User Settings* at the bottom of the *User Preferences* panel. This will make it so that you can use these keys every time you open Blender, rather than having to change the user preferences every time.

*The File menu:*

[image]

*The User Preferences window:*

[image]

Comment: @Tsakov glad to hear it. If you like it, please consider accepting it. Click the checkmark at the top left of my answer. It would help me greatly and make me very happy!